# htaccess redirect all domains to one domain, except one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

There are severals (a lot) domains that need to be redirected to one main domain. 
Right now it's done with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But now the webspace needs to listen to a second Domain. So this second domain (and all subdomains) need to be exclude from the rule above.

some more examples:

```
www.maindomain.com        => no redirect
maindomain.com            => www.maindomain.com
*.maindomain.com          => www.maindomain.com
domain.com                => www.maindomain.com
www.domain.com            => www.maindomain.com
domain-something.com      => www.maindomain.com
www.domain-something.com  => www.maindomain.com

www.second-maindomain.com => no redirect
second-maindomain.com     => www.second-maindomain.com
*.second-maindomain.com   => www.second-maindomain.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !second-maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.second-maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.second-maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Almost. But every subdomain from second-maindomain.com returns a 200 status code.

Comment: your answer worked with some changes.

I removed the typo in the last line. 
And i added a www. to the third Cond.

Comment: I have corrected the typo; as for www, it should not make a difference (if the request host is xxx.maindomain.com, it should never reach that point), this is regex so maindomain.com covers the www.maindomain.com case also .